# Select all form elements using jquery except those that are hidden by CSS

Tags: jquery, css, selector, hidden, visible

I want to select all form elements using jQuery, which I know I can do using

```
$(':input')
```

but then I don't want to select elements that are hidden by CSS, which I can do with

```
$(':input:visible')
```

but the one thing that I *do* want to get are these:

```
<input type="hidden" />
```

I'm just not wanting to get element that are hidden because either they or their parent is hidden with something like:

```
style="display:none;"
```

etc

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it can be done with a single selector

Comment: either try something like `$(':input:visible').add($('input[type="hidden"]'))`

Comment: or you may have to use a `.filter()` like `$(':input').filter(function(){
    return (this.type.toUpperCase() == 'HIDDEN' && !$(this).parent().is(':hidden')) || !$(this).is(':hidden');
})`

Comment: Arun: your first solution is what worked for me.  If you'll create it as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: done... posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(':input').filter(function () {
    return (this.type.toUpperCase() == 'HIDDEN' && !$(this).parent().is(':hidden')) || !$(this).is(':hidden');
})
```

or

```
(':input:visible').add($('input[type="hidden"]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Attribute not equal selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

```
$("input[type!='hidden']" ).css( "border", "3px dotted green" );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/LqqLL/

Comment: Nope.  I *do* want the type = hidden elements.  I *don't* want anything that is hidden with style="display:none;" or who have a parent hidden like that.  Make sense?  Points for the fiddle, though!